# GUI, arranging buttons inside a panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How to i display the buttons right?

heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class cal extends JFrame

{

private JLabel monthnym, monnym,tuesnym,wednym,thunym,frinym,satnym,sunnym;
private JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,
b19,b20,b21,b22,b23,b24,b25,b26,b27,b28,b29,b30;
private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3,panel4;
public cal()
{
    super("November");
    Container c = getContentPane();

    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,5));
    panel1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
    monthnym=new JLabel("November 2013");
    panel1.add(monthnym);

    panel2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,7,2,2));
    sunnym=new JLabel("SUN");
    monnym=new JLabel("MON");
    tuesnym=new JLabel("TUE");
    wednym=new JLabel("WED");
    thunym=new JLabel("THU");
    frinym=new JLabel("FRI");
    satnym=new JLabel("SAT");
    panel2.add(sunnym);
    panel2.add(monnym);
    panel2.add(tuesnym);
    panel2.add(wednym);
    panel2.add(thunym);
    panel2.add(frinym);
    panel2.add(satnym);

    panel3=new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,7,3,3));
    b1=new JButton("1");
    b2=new JButton("2");
    b3=new JButton("3");
    b4=new JButton("4");
    b5=new JButton("5");

    panel3.add(b1);
    panel3.add(b2);
    panel3.add(b3);
    panel3.add(b4);
    panel3.add(b5);



    //panel4=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,7,5,5));
    c.add(panel1);
    c.add(panel2);
    c.add(panel3);
    //c.add(panel4);
    setSize(500,500);
    show();
}








public static void main(String[] args) {

    cal app = new cal();

}

}
```

i edit my code severwal times, but no luck.
 i think theres something in the (x,y) but i nothing change.

and those buttons are 30, i redused it to 5 cause i get error posting this question

Comment: Q- How do you want them displayed?

Comment: normal width and heigth for buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, `GridLayout` is reserving space for what it thinks it needs, but because the area it wants is larger then the area you've provided, it's squeezed every thing.

If I change the layout manager for the content pane from `c.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 5));` to `c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` I get...

[image]

My first recommendation is to use better layouts.  You've already broken the code down into separate components, which is a good start, you can use different layout managers for each of  these sections to generate a better layout.

You may need to consider placing you UI into a `JScrollPane` if it simply won't fit into a (reasonable) screen...

You should also use `JFrame#pack` to size the main frame instead of `setSize` where possible.

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some ideas.

Next, I would suggest that you generate a custom component which maintains the basic content, so you can re-use.

I would also encourage you to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and ensure that your UI is constructed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread to prevent possible issues.

I would also encourage you to place your buttons into an array or `List` of some kind, instead of creating 30 named variables...IMHO

Comment: thank you sir, that idea is brilliant, but, the only topic that discussed is gridlayout. and that is an activity that i stucked in. hope you can help me with this

Comment: Start by taking a read through [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,5));
```

and

```
panel3=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,7,1,1));
```

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by @MadProgrammer try to use different LayoutManagers for panels. I change your code a little. I set [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for your container, now it looks better.

```
public class Form extends JFrame {

    private JLabel monthnym, monnym, tuesnym, wednym, thunym, frinym, satnym,
            sunnym;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;

    public Form() {
        super("November");
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        monthnym = new JLabel("November 2013");
        panel1.add(monthnym);

        panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        sunnym = new JLabel("SUN");
        monnym = new JLabel("MON");
        tuesnym = new JLabel("TUE");
        wednym = new JLabel("WED");
        thunym = new JLabel("THU");
        frinym = new JLabel("FRI");
        satnym = new JLabel("SAT");
        panel2.add(sunnym);
        panel2.add(monnym);
        panel2.add(tuesnym);
        panel2.add(wednym);
        panel2.add(thunym);
        panel2.add(frinym);
        panel2.add(satnym);

        panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 7));
        for(int i =0;i<30;i++){
            JButton b = new JButton(""+i);
            panel3.add(b);
        }

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridy =0;
        c.add(panel1,gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        c.add(panel2,gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        c.add(panel3,gbc);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Form app = new Form();
    }

 }
```

[image]

Also use `pack()` instead of `setSize()`, and `setVisible(true)` instead of deprecated `show()`